# Encode as json object and send it via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have found this: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json, a plugin that emulates json_encode PHP function.

So I tried this:

```
var datasend = {};
    datasend['name'] = $(".chat_username").val();
    datasend['message'] = $(".chat_text").val();
    encoded_send = $.toJSON( datasend );
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/apps/chat_write",
      data: {send_data: encoded_send },
      success: function(response){
        if(response!="OK"){
            alert("Παρουσιάστηκε πρόβλημα.Κάντε ανανέωση την σελίδα ή προσπαθήστε ξανά αργότερα.");
        }else{
            $(".chat_text").val("");
            $(".chat_count").val("0/100");
        }
      }
    });
```

The first problem?I have this

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/apps/chat_write",
      data: "name="+escape($(".chat_username").val())+"&message="+escape($(".chat_text").val()),
      success: function(response){
        if(response!="OK"){
            alert("Παρουσιάστηκε πρόβλημα.Κάντε ανανέωση την σελίδα ή προσπαθήστε ξανά αργότερα.");
        }else{
            $(".chat_text").val("");
            $(".chat_count").val("0/100");
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
});
```

And i have problems with greek characters..
so i decidied to use json object
If this code is correct how can I parse the JSON object from PHP? If it's not correct where are the errors?

Thanks

Comment: Use the [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) PHP function. Your code makes no sense though, because you're declaring a variable `encoded_send`, and not using it. Then, you're using `JSON.stringify(jsonObjects)` without defining `jsonObjects`.

Comment: `json_decode($_POST['send_data']);` doesn't work

Comment: oupssss... `JSON.stringify(encoded_send)`

Comment: Fyi, `Array`s do not have named keys. You want `datasend = {};` (which is equal to `new Object()`) instead! And there is no reason to use a "jquery json plugin" since it's completely DOM or jQuery-unrelated. The preferred JSON parser is https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js - it especially has a fallback to builtin functions if available.

Comment: `encoded_send` is already JSON I assume. Why would you want to encode it again?

Comment: `application/j-son` is incorrect, too. The correct type is `application/json` without the dash.

Comment: @FelixKling fixed...
But the problem still exists

Comment: @ThiefMaster fixed this error..
Any other errors?

Comment: Well, does it work? If not, debug your code.

Comment: Doesn't work..
How can i debug my code..
I update the changes into my question

Comment: You debug your code by locking for error messages, inspect variables and see whether they have the value you expect, etc. Then you analyze the error messages and resolve the problems. That's what error messages are there for, to tell you what is wrong. For example the message you posted as comment on the other answer tells you that `$decode_data` is an object and not an array. So you have to either access it as an object or make `json_decode` return an array. Both can be find in the documentation.

Comment: @ChrisPappas: just as a FYI, you have a syntax error in your first snippet. When you define all you `var`s with a single `var` statement, you need to end the statement in a comma. Only the last one should end in a semicolon. Your current syntax defines one local `var`, the rest are "accidental" globals.

Answer (score 1):

*(before I continue to your function..)*
You seem to misunderstand the purpose of JSON. It's not necessary to replace the data with a JSON string when transmitting data to a server. A much easier approach is adding parameters through `data`, and retrieving them through `$_POST`.

Example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/apps/chat_write",
    data: {
        name: $(".chat_username").val(),
        message: $(".chat_text").val()
    },
    dataType: "json", /* This parameter is ONLY used at the response */
    success: function(response){
        //response is a deserialized JSON string
    }
});
```

Simple PHP example:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $example = array("what" => "This");
    echo json_encode($example); //Echos: {"what":"This"}
?>
```

JSON should be used in a server respons. PHP objects can be serialized using `json_encode`. Make sure that you use `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before sending any output.

*(if you still want to JSON-encode data before sending)*
Use the [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) PHP function to deserialize a JSON string.

Your current code has to be fixed though.

```
var datasend = {};
datasend['name'] = $(".chat_username").val();
datasend['message'] = $(".chat_text").val();
var encoded_send = $.toJSON( datasend );
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/apps/chat_write",
  data: {send_data: encoded_send },
  dataType: "json", /* Can be removed if the RESPONSE is not JSON*/
  success: function(response){
    if(response!="OK"){
        alert("Παρουσιάστηκε πρόβλημα.Κάντε ανανέωση την σελίδα ή προσπαθήστε ξανά αργότερα.");
    }else{
        $(".chat_text").val("");
        $(".chat_count").val("0/100");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Btw, I don't think the MIME type has to be overridden, jQuery will still encode the data as `x-www-form-urlencoded`: `send_data={json_here}`.

Comment: Now i take this error: `<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\apps\chat\chat_write.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />`

Comment: Try this PHP code in conjunction with my suggested JavaScript code: http://pastebin.com/NgdDxmgN